# Why are there lots of responses initially and then no new answers?

Tags: discussion

I have observed in the few questions that i have asked that initially there is a spurt of responses followed by a lot of cross-questioning, edits, debating, etc. This dies out in a few hours at most, leaving just one or two more responses that come in maybe the next day.

Beyond that i have not seen any activity, even though there might not be any satisfactory answer to the question.

So, is there some part that i am missing here ?

Or is this the normal behavior/community response to a question ?

[I have asked very exact questions as well as a discussion-type question, both getting similar response]

**EDIT** : IF this is the normal behaviour, then this means that the answers you get depends only on the time that you ask the question as votes, commments are most likely when there are others watching the questions page. How is this something that SO wants ? 
Havent there been improvements/changes for the system so as to avoid this situation ?

[As there would be members here from all over the world, this would mean that certain users will have an easier time getting better answers from experts as opposed to someone who lives in a timezone which happens to be at 2 am, when its the best time for getting answers.
And NO, every country, region, does not have experts]

Comment: if you edit your question, It will bump  it to the top of the list

Comment: Isnt there a code of ethics saying not to do that ? ;)

Comment: well you should try to improve your question when you do that.  at the very least

Comment: @AshRj If you bump it too many times like that, it will force the post into wiki. That said, there are many loopholes around this, but it isn't abused enough to motivate a change in policy.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions) is a resource for explaining how to get attention for older unanswered questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this is normal behavior.

When you ask a new question it shows up in the [Newest Questions lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest). So many people will see it.
Likewise, when you edit a post, it bumps the question back into the [Active Questions list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) (as well as the Stackoverflow homepage).

As mentioned in the comments, there is also an [Unanswered Questions list](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) which many users frequent.

After a few hours of inactivity, the question falls off those lists so few people will see them anymore.

This is the case with the vast majority of questions. Occasionally a question is "good enough" to accumulate enough votes in that critical first few hours. In such a case it will appear in the hot-lists which will attract more attention over a greater period of time.

---

As per your edit:

Yes, the time of the day is a major factor in how many people are online. But during peak hours, not only are there many more answerers, but there are also many more questions competing for the same attention. So it somewhat "cancels out" in the end.

During peak hours, a question may get more viewers in a short amount of time. But at the same time, the question will fall off the "new" and "active" lists faster.

- In the big tags, the time of the day will affect how *quickly* your question gets an answer. But it will probably have a negligible affect how *likely* your question gets an answer.
- In the more specialized topics, there are fewer questions. So users who are active in the topic will likely find your question anyway - even if it's not on the "new", "active", or "unanswered" lists.

So in the end, I don't think it makes a difference if you just want your question answered.
Now if you're trying to game the system for upvotes and reputation, then yes, the time of the day seems to matter very much. But that's a different topic that I won't get into.

---

For example, I'm active in C and C++ with specialization in performance and optimization.

The C and C++ tags are very busy with many users. So I only answer if they are new and I see them on the front page. If I miss one, who cares? There are *many* other users that can (and will) answer them.

But in the performance and optimization tags, I'm one of only a handful of regular users. So questions in those tags can easily go unanswered for hours. Unlike the C and C++ tags, I actively search out performance/optimization questions. So if there's a question that I want to answer, I will eventually find and answer it (if nobody else has done so satisfactorily) - regardless of when it was asked.

Comment: In addition, a lot of people browse the [Unanswered](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) list to find questions to answer, which shows you questions with no positively voted answers. Once you get a positively scored answer, your question is removed from that list too.

Comment: @Rachel and of course [there are](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/126/revival) some [badges for that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer).

Comment: So, if initial responses are not clear/good/inaccurate, then the chances of getting a better answer are nil ? [General topics, not specialized]
<br/>
How is this desirable for SO quality ?

Comment: @AshRj Your making the assumption that those who see it early will provide sub-par answers. That simply isn't true. In general topics, virtually everyone in the area is fully capable providing a full and complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is going to succeed on stackoverflow.com, it will, most likely, succeed fairly rapidly. By 'succeed,' I mean 'attract a correct, factual, answer to your practical problem.' You do, of course, pose problems that are real, practical problems, just like the FAQ tells you to -- right?

If a question doesn't find a person who owns an answer within a short time, it's not *impossible* that it will find one later -- just less likely.

And if a question requires a great deal of back-and-forth in comments, then it *might* not be a great example of a question that will succeed here. If the question turns out to be about some very specific aspect of your very specific situation, that requires a discussion to tease it out, it *might* really be 'too localized'.

Or not. YMMV.

Comment: <pre>"If your question is going to succeed on stackoverflow.com, it will, most likely, succeed fairly rapidly"

This assumes that there is someone online at the time who knows of what you are asking or is knowledgeable enough to answer, which is exactly what i am saying as well. 

Also getting an answer later on is improbable, yes. Impossible, not at all and neither did i say that.

The back and forth does not always depend on the question. Answers at times may be controversial or the author's own view disguised as fact. This generates most of the debates i have seen.</pre>